# How to set up the basic page to get PrimeNg global theme styles work

Tags: angular, primeng

**Situation:**

I set up my Angular 11 app with PrimeNg 11 successfully by doing the *[Get started](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/showcase/#/setup)*. I have chosen the dark theme "Vela Orange" and therefore included the CSS in `styles` within `angular.json`. PrimeNg components are styled correctly. Ripples and animations work too. So this part worked well.

**Problem:**

The basic page background is still white and the font is Times in black color. It looks like the global styles are not applied. I searched the documentation and google what I need to put in place so I get the basic theme styles on globally. Do I have to put something on my HTML "body" tag or is there a root component that set's the global stage for the PrimeNg theme.

How to I get a very basic app with the themes background and font set?
What do I miss here?

Answer (score 0):

Try importing the css in your global style.css.

@import url("../node_modules/primeicons/primeicons.css");
@import url("../node_modules/primeng/resources/themes/vela-orange/theme.css");
@import url("../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css");